# wp_get_attachment_image_src returning full size images

Tags: wordpress

In functions.php, I have:

```
add_image_size( 'coach-profile-pic', 88, 113, true);
```

In my template, I have:

```
$pic = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $picture['profile_pic'][0], 'coach-profile-pic' );
```

For some images, they're being returned in full size while others are being returned as 88x113 (as expected).  All of the images were uploaded after the custom image size was added to functions.php  For the images that are being returned as full size, I've checked and the 88x113 size of that image exists on the server.  I can't figure out why full size images are being returned rather than the custom image size. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try regenerating the images (http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

Comment: I agree with @dwhite.me. Maybe the thumbnails don't exist yet in your uploads dir. the regenerate-thumbnails plugin will create thumbnails from scratch for all of your images.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that some of the pictures do NOT have proper sizes to return. You have to check if you generate proper size photos when you add them to db.

Normally when I import files into wp I do something like:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

Of course it's only sample, and you have to adapt it into your script and generate proper size of image. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing the site localy, chances are high, that you don't have the libs in php, to resize images. So the images never get resized. Not even if you use a plugin like regenerate thumbnails advanced. As soon as I tried the site development on my webhosting in a subdomain, images got resized properly and the problem was gone.